# Delete character before last digit in Notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

I want to delete a minus sign before the last digit in a string. Strings are like `08131 66678-0`. I'm looking for `-\d{1}` and find it.

With what should a replace the search to delet the minus? I try to replace it with `\d{1}` - but i get a string with added `\d{1}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use

```
-(?=\d$)
```

and replace with an empty string. Or, a capturing group + backreference can be used:

```
-(\d$)
```

to replace with `$1`.

Here,

- `-` - matches and consumes the hyphen (i.e. the `-` is put into the match value to be replaced)
  -`(?=\d$)` - a positive lookahead that only checks if there is a digit followed with the end of the line, but the digit is not added to the match value and won't get replaced

  - `(\d$)` - a capturing group that consumes the digit at the end of string, and puts the value into group memory buffer that can be addressed using the `$1` placeholder from the replacement pattern.

If the values are not at the end of lines, you may use a word boundary after the digit pattern, `\b`, or a negative lookahead `(?!\d)` (making sure there is no digit immediately to the right of the current location) instead of `$`.